# Glitch robbed me 2 reputation

Tags: support

I think this is where to ask about this, but not totally sure, so appologies if i'm off-topic.

I had a glitch happen on my phone when I went to check on one of my own questions. It was not showing I had accepted the answer, though I thought I had the day before (and I had).  I went to accept it, which seemed to do nothing at all, like the page was locked-up.  Then it kind of did some wierd janky stuff and seemed to confuse my browser for a moment.  Anyway, basically what ended up happening was it unaccepted and re-accepted my answer, as you can see in the pic, and took two points off my rep, but didnt put them back when re-accepted.  May have been a wifi issue, as I was in a spot where the signal drops out from time to time.  Any way I can fix this?  It's only two points, but kind of sucks since unaccepting my answer was the opposite of my intentions.  I'm a little new to Stack Exchange as a member, but I'm trying contribute back to what has turned into a revolving gold-mine of valuable insight.  Thanks to anyone who can help!

[image]

Comment: It is not a glitch.  You decided to un-accept Thomas' answer, so -2 to correct the rep increase you got on Oct 10th.  Then accepted your own answer, so +0.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: You lost 2 reputation for unaccepting the *other user's* answer. You do not ever get reputation for accepting *your own* answer.

Comment: There definitely _was_ a glitch.  When I touched the checkbox the page jerked up and down, then locked up for almost a minute-- probably due to a bad signal.    I understand, now that I have asked a knowledgable audience, it was not the cause of the point loss.  It _was_, however, the cause for _asking_ about it.  This is not a duplicate question.  I thought I had already accepted my own answer the day before.  It seemed like it wasnt showing and I had unchecked my answer by trying to check it, because that was the percieved context between the timing of the messages, and the glitch itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initially gained 2 rep by accepting another user's answer. StackOverflow does not give you any rep for accepting your own answer. Therefore, when you unaccepted his (-2) and accepted yours (+0) you got the correct net (-2).

If your answer is truly better than the other user's, that's the end of it. It's not worth two rep to accept bad or incomplete answers, that will just pollute the site. And if the other user's answer was better, why bother posting your own answer at all?

Comment: Ah.  Now I see.  Yes, I forgot I accepted his answer initially, then changed it to mine since his didnt quite fit what I was asking.  One thing he mentioned (SGR) did help a related issue later. I think that was my original reasoning... but the closest answer to my question was the one I posted, which was why I switched it up.  Point being, someone else will get a working solution from my post, albeit not as simple as I had hoped.  For some reason I thought it was +2 for accepting your own answer, and +5 for accepting another's.  Don't want lose rep due to a glitch.  Thanks all for the info!

Comment: Hmmm...  I don't get it.  What's with all the down-votes on the question?

Comment: Your title says it was a glitch, @jdmayfield, but it wasn't a glitch. The system was working as intended. Note that downvotes on Meta are a bit different than downvotes elsewhere, as they often indicate disagreement and are even more heavily biased towards lack of research effort being a reason to downvote (read as: lack of familiarity with how the site is intended to work). Some of this is explained in the Help Center article, [What is Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). The good news is, there's no reputation on Meta (it just shows your rep on the main site).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Cody .  The glitch I referred to was on my phone due a connectivity issue.  We have Consolidated Communications.  Supposedly it's fiber, but we are plagued by dropouts on the other side of the box.  Unreliable, but it's my landlords choice so I'm stuck with it.  At the time I thought I had already changed the accepted answer, and was unsure what happened.  I erred in my understanding of specific points involved (maybe crossed memories of another site?).  I appologize.  I didn't realize it at the time.  Will be more careful.   Should I delete this question?